# js function accepting and producing correct data but is outputting incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

I am building a picture box with thumbnails using jQuery/js, whereby clicking a thumbnail shows the image in a larger box. I have a function that should then measure the dimensions of the large image and adjust it and/or the image's absolute position within a div container to make it best fit.

Adjustment function code (*#main-img* is the div container):

```
    function mainImageSize(w, h){
    var containerWidth = parseInt($("#main-img").css("width"));
    var containerHeight = parseInt($("#main-img").css("height"));
    var imgWidth = parseInt(w);
    var imgHeight = parseInt(h);
    alert(imgHeight);
    var widthCenter = Math.round((containerWidth / 2) - (imgWidth / 2));
    var heightCenter = Math.round((containerHeight / 2) - (imgHeight / 2));
    if(imgWidth > imgHeight){
        if (imgHeight >= containerHeight || imgHeight == containerHeight){ 
            $("#main-image").children("img").css("width", "auto");
            $("#main-image").children("img").css("height", containerHeight + "px");
        } 
        else {
            $("#main-image").children("img").css("top", heightCenter + "px");
            $("#main-image").children("img").css("left", widthCenter + "px");
        };
    } else {
        if (imgWidth >= containerWidth || imgWidth == containerWidth){ 
            $("#main-image").children("img").css("height", "auto");
            $("#main-image").children("img").css("width", containerWidth + "px");
        } 
        else {
            $("#main-image").children("img").css("top", heightCenter + "px");
            $("#main-image").children("img").css("left", widthCenter + "px");
        };
    };
};
```

Click function code (within $(document).ready):

```
    $("#images a").click(function(){
        var imagePath = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
        $("#main-img").children("img").attr("src", imagePath);
        var srcWidth = $("#main-img img").css("width");
        var srcHeight = $("#main-img img").css("height");
        mainImageSize(srcWidth, srcHeight);
        return false;
    });
```

The problem I am having is that mainImageSize() does not seem to output correctly. I have placed alerts at several different points within it, all of which present the correct data, but the function has no effect upon the image.

Am I missing one or more returns? I didn't think so, as I have used similar functions on a separate page that appear to work.

Any thoughts?

Edit 1:

Here is the relevant html code

```
    <?php 
            $folder = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event-images', true);
            if($folder){
                $folder_path = "wp-content/themes/blankslate/images/events/event/$folder/";
                if(file_exists($folder_path)) { ?>
                <div id="image-area" class="clearfix">
                    <?php $images = glob($folder_path . "*.{jpg,png,gif,JPG,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE); ?>
                    <div id="main-img"><img src="/<?php echo $images[0]; ?>" alt="Event image" /></div>
                    <div id="thumbs-container">
                        <a class="arrow" href="#"></a>
                        <div id="images-wrap">
                            <div id="images">
                                <?php foreach($images as $image){ ?>
                                    <a href=""><img src="/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Thumbnail" /></a>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="arrow" href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end image area -->
            <?php }
            } ?>
```

I can't seem to get the CSS to format properly in this editor; the standard method for writing out a code block produces some odd results....However, `#main-img` has `position: relative;` and `#main-img img` has `position:absolute;`

Comment: Give us the HTML to match with your CSS.  Better yet, make a http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can see what you're doing

Comment: Oh and everywhere you have `$("#main-img").children("img")` - just use  `$('#main-img > img')`  -  and I hope there's only one `#main-img` on the whole page.

Comment: The html includes php so I will post it here rather than jsfiddle.

`<div id="image-area" class="clearfix">
<?php $images = glob($folder_path . "*.{jpg,png,gif,JPG,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE); ?>
<div id="main-img"><img src="/<?php echo $images[0]; ?>" alt="Event image" /></div>
<div id="thumbs-container">
<a class="arrow" href="#"></a>
<div id="images-wrap">
<div id="images">
<?php foreach($images as $image){ ?>
<a href=""><img src="/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Thumbnail" /></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<a class="arrow" href="#"></a>
</div>
</div><!-- end image area -->`

Yes, only one main-img

Comment: Excuse the poor formatting here!

Comment: You should edit the question to add that in. Also, you set the `top` and `left` properties, but those only work on positioned elements. Is the img positioned? Besides, this would set the top left corner of the img to the center of the container, is that right?

Comment: What were you trying to do with `if (imgWidth >= containerWidth || imgWidth == containerWidth)`? That doesn't really make sense, unless it's a desperate attempt to make something work.

Comment: Post edited. As for the line `if (imgHeight >= containerHeight || imgHeight == containerHeight)`, the reason for that is that I was working on the page halfway through a night shift :) Looking at it now, I realise why this is unnecessary, so thankyou for pointing that out!

Comment: Is that entire HTML code in a PHP `for()` loop?

Comment: No, just the very middle that outputs images inside anchors. The rest occurs once, and is inside this statement: `if(file_exists($folder_path)) { //code here }`

Comment: The code that is output by the for loop is what the second block of jQuery above refers to.

Comment: Can anybody offer up a suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out, and now feel pretty stupid...

Within the mainImageSize() function, throughout the entirety of the main if/else statement, I was referring to `$("#main-image")`

This should have been `$("#main-img")`

Always turns out to be something simple! *facepalm*